# Mysql query does not look right

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to update a field in my table based in another table and I executed this query below but I think it's not right.. it looks like it worked but is it correct? Is there any situation where it might fail?

```
UPDATE users SET page = (SELECT page_name FROM pages WHERE user_id = id)
```

My table USERS has a column id and page. My table PAGES has a column page_name and user_id. Is the code above right?

Comment: why not write the select statement seperate and fetch it put it in a variable, then use the variable to update page?

Comment: Check for errors - what happens if you run the query? Perhaps `id` is ambiguous. Or are you looking for a specific user-ID? Because this updates every row that exist in both tables.

Comment: This is going to update every row of the table

Comment: may (or may not...) be the intended result?

Comment: if you're looking to keep a relation of 1-1 with the page and automate the update process why don't you use foreign keys and update cascade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may fail if pages has more than one page_name per user_id. I find `UPDATE a INNER JOIN b ON some_conditions SET a.fieldA = b.fieldB;` to be much more readable. It does have the same failure scenario, and can be harder to "fix" for such scenarios; but correlated subqueries (your version) tend to be significantly slower.

Also, style note, `UPDATE users AS u SET u.page = (SELECT p.page_name FROM pages AS p WHERE p.user_id = u.id);` would've eliminated the need for your last two sentences and (more importantly):

- make it so the next developer that has to look at the query does not have to look at the database to find out (or remember) what fields go to what tables.
- make it so the query does not break if an `id` field later gets added to `pages`.

Comment: Not just the next developer either, could very potentially be you six months down the line trying to decipher what the heck the query actually does.  I've personally been burned on stuff like this in the past.

Comment: Yeah, that is why I included "or remember". Often the "next developer" is you; months or years down the line, with half a dozen projects worked on between then and now, and the first thing you think is "I wrote this?"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of subselect  In mysql  you can use UPDATE JOIN

```
  UPDATE users 
  INNER JOIN pages on pages.user_id = users.id
  SET users.page = pages.page_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have more than one table in a query, you should always use qualified column names -- and preferably aliases.  So, your version of the query would be:

```
UPDATE users u
     SET page = (SELECT p.page_name FROM pages p WHERE p.user_id = u.id);
```

Next, you have to consider whether the subquery might return more than one row.  If so, you have to limit it to one row.  There are various ways, `SELECT MAX(p.page_name)`, `LIMIT 1`, and `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(p.page_name)` all come to mind.

Next, you are updating all rows in `users`.  If you only want to update matching rows, then you can continue on the subquery path using `IN` or `EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause.  Alternatively, use `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE users u JOIN
       pages p
       ON p.user_id = u.id
     SET u.page = p.page_name;
```

But most importantly, ask the existential question:  Why do you need to do this update?  You have a link between the two tables.   Use the link instead of storing the name:

```
select u.*, p.page_name
from users u left join
     pages p
     on p.user_id = u.id;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below sample SQL and change as per your requirement.The Code above seems correct .Could you please paste the error

```
UPDATE TableB 
SET TableB.value = (
    SELECT TableA.value 
    FROM TableA
    WHERE TableA.name = TableB.name
);
```

Comment: this question states it is for mysql, and in mysql update, inner join is much faster. scaisEdge is correct. Your solution will work on any SQL DBMS, but his is contextually best